# How to add many values to an array in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

My if statements are only adding one element to the arrays even though they should add several as several have identical tags.

```
<?php

include("mysqlconnect.php");

$select_query = "SELECT `ImagesId`,`ImagesPath`,`Tag` FROM `offerstbl` ORDER by `ImagesId` DESC";
$sql = mysql_query($select_query) or die(mysql_error());   

$data = array();

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_BOTH)){
    if ($rows['Tag'] == "sport"){
      $data['sport'] = array($rows['ImagesId'], $rows['ImagesPath'], $rows['Tag']);
    }
    if ($rows['Tag'] == "food"){
      $data['food'] = array($rows['ImagesId'], $rows['ImagesPath'], $rows['Tag']);
    }
   if ($rows['Tag'] == "clothes"){
      $data['clothes'] = array($rows['ImagesId'], $rows['ImagesPath'], $rows['Tag']);
    }
}

 echo json_encode($data);


 ?>
```

Comment: `switch`, `case`, `break` to make it neater perhaps?

Comment: You don't need `$data = array();`, but that won't matter. What do you mean one element, one element as in one array? Please make clear. I'm guessing you need to do this: `$data[]['sport'] = `. You probably need a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the array element instead of pushing a new element onto the array. It should be:

```
$data['sport'][] = array($rows['ImagesId'], $rows['ImagesPath'], $rows['Tag']);
```

Also, your `if` seems unnecessary, since the keys of `$data` are identical to the tags. Just do:

```
$data[$rows['Tag']][] = array($rows['ImagesId'], $rows['ImagesPath'], $rows['Tag']);
```

I also recommend using associative arrays for the elements that you're adding, not indexed arrays:

```
$data[$rows['Tag']][] = array('ImagesId' => $rows['ImagesId'], 
                              'ImagesPath' => $rows['ImagesPath'], 
                              'Tag' => $rows['Tag']);
```

And since these keys are the same as the keys in `$rows`, you can simplify it to:

```
$data[$rows['Tag']][] = $rows;
```

You should also use `MYSQL_ASSOC` rather than `MYSQL_BOTH`, since you're never accessing the numeric keys of `$rows`.

Answer (score 0):

You must change three lines from your code

```
$data['sport'] = array($rows['ImagesId'], $rows['ImagesPath'], $rows['Tag']);
```

to

```
$data['sport'][] = array($rows['ImagesId'], $rows['ImagesPath'], $rows['Tag']);
```

This

```
$data['food'] = array($rows['ImagesId'], $rows['ImagesPath'], $rows['Tag']);
```

to

```
$data['food'][] = array($rows['ImagesId'], $rows['ImagesPath'], $rows['Tag']);
```

This

```
$data['clothes'] = array($rows['ImagesId'], $rows['ImagesPath'], $rows['Tag']);
```

to

```
$data['clothes'][] = array($rows['ImagesId'], $rows['ImagesPath'], $rows['Tag']);
```